# Swift TableView does not displaying data

Tags: uikit

I want to display two sections Films and Serials.But tableview doesn't`t display data.I don't why
I tried to add
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
in StoryBoard.
I check if reusableIdentifier is correct, it is correct
But it didn't solve the problem

```
// ViewController.swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var MyTableView: UITableView!
    
    var tableViewDataSource: [String: [TestModel]] = [
        "Films": [
            TestModel(_title: "First", _description: "This is my first cell"),
            TestModel(_title: "Second", _description: "This is my second cell"),
            TestModel(_title: "Third", _description: "This is my third cell")
        ],
        "Serials": [
            TestModel(_title: "Batman", _description: "Description Batman"),
            TestModel(_title: "Supernatural", _description: "Some info"),
            TestModel(_title: "Helloworld", _description: "Hellol")
        ]
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}
```

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let key = Array(tableViewDataSource.keys)[section]
        return tableViewDataSource[key]?.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "testCell") as! PrototypeTableViewCell
        
        let key = Array(tableViewDataSource.keys)[indexPath.section]
        
        cell.titleLabel.text = tableViewDataSource[key]![indexPath.row].title
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = tableViewDataSource[key]![indexPath.row].description
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return tableViewDataSource.count
    }
    
    
}
```

```
//TestModel.swift
class TestModel {
    var title: String?
    var description: String?
    
    init(_title: String, _description: String) {
        title = _title
        description = _description
    }
}
```

Comment: In `viewDidLoad()` add this line: `MyTableView.dataSource = self` and see if you get your rows displayed.

Comment: I have done it but I didn't get my rows displayed

Comment: titleForHeaderInSection are displayed but rows doesn't

Comment: Is the code you posted the actual code you are using? Because it doesn't show a `titleForHeaderInSection` implementation. Using your code, I have no trouble seeing the table view rows filled with data. Try putting together a [mre] and post it somewhere such as GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should add MyTableView.dataSource = self
2. May be the problem with that line of code:
   return tableViewDataSource[key]?.count ?? 0 in numberOfRowsInSection.

I advice you to create simple array for example:
var tableViewDataSource = ["1", "2", "3"]

and after that put it in numberOfRowsInSection:

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableViewDataSource.count
}
```

The first stage - try to check numberOfRowsInSection.